# Why do these two command give different outputs?

Tags: python, escaping, subprocess

**Command 1:**

```
subprocess.call(["echo","\"hw\""])
```

**Output:**

```
"hw"
```

**Command2 :**

```
subprocess.call(["echo","""hw"""])
```

**Output:**

```
hw
```

Comment: """some string""" == "some string"

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first command passes the quotes to the `echo` system command, and thus is equivalent to doing this on the command line:

```
$ echo "hw"
```

Your second command only passes the `hw` string (no quotes) to `echo` and is equivalent to the following:

```
$ echo hw
```

In your second command, you're using the **docstring** notation for strings, which is equivalent to `"hw"` as well as `'hw'`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!